# Get props (or global variables)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm attempting to set some global variables on my app which I want to be available to all components. Lets say for example that I want a 'language' and a 'status' property to be passed to each component. This property won't be rendered to the page, instead it will be added to the props for each component, this will be so I can check for that variable when each component loads and output the appropriate styles and languages.

I was hoping it would be something simple like adding props to the router, however no matter what I try, the props come back as 'undefined' on my child components (only the main layoutWrapper component gets the props). Here is how it looks so far:

```
//app.js

var LayoutWrapper = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
        <Layout status="available" />
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
   <Route path="/" language="en-gb" component={LayoutWrapper}>
     <IndexRoute component={Index}></IndexRoute>
   </Route>
  </Router>,
app);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When handling global level state data, it's recommended you use some kind of state framework like Flux. I'd recommend [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) as it does a great job of reducing boilerplate code to easily pass down app state to any connected component (and subsequently subscribe these components to any changes in the state).

What you are doing fails because there's no consistent way of creating "global" props; you could use the `context` variable but this is an unstable feature that is not recommended for production use. Otherwise, you have to manually pass down your props from parent to child explicitly.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I have used flux to give each component a state (taken from a mongodb instance) but I didn't realise I could use it outside of components. I'll take a look at Redux, I didn't realise that was the same thing as flux, I was gonna learn redux later.

Comment: Yeah the whole point of a state framework is to help share state between components not hierarchically related (and those that are as well if it makes sense to do so). Redux has a few advantages over Flux like having a single store (making it easier to keep track of state), time traveling, and hot reloading.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I was really not happy that I had to create different stores for each component, it seemed like a lot of repetition. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. And while you learn Redux, I highly recommend watching the creator's (Dan Abramov) free videos. They are the single most informational sources of help when learning Redux (and `react-redux`): https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux